# How to successfully restart loop and accept new responses?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a program that can print ascii art letters when given J, E, or C and the size (7 or greater and an odd number). I have been able to successfully run the program until I added a Y/N response prompt. I would like to ask the user if they would like to continue, if yes, then I would like to restart the loop. However, I'm trying to write the code to meet the conditions of if they enter 'e' then 'e' ascii art prints, if they enter 'c' then ascii art prints, etc. However,  I cannot figure out how to restart the loop and accept new information. 
Also, my current predicament is that the do loop is not meeting with my last while loop for a 'No' response. I'm new to C++ and would appreciate any help that can be provided. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int s;
  char l;
  char choice;

  cout << "Welcome to the letter printer." << endl;

  do {
    cout << "Enter the size: " << endl;
    cin >> s;

    while (s < 7 || s % 2 == 0 || s < 0) {
      cout << "Invalid size. Enter the size again: " << endl;
      cin >> s;
    }

    cout << "Enter the letter: " << endl;
    cin >> l;

    while (l != 'c') {
      cout << "Invalid letter. Enter the letter again: " << endl;
      cin >> l;
    }

    if (l == 'c') {
      int size = s;
      for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        cout << "*";
        for (int col = 0; col < size - 1; col++) {
          if (row == size - 1)
            cout << "*";
          else
            cout << " ";
          if (row == 0)
            cout << "*";
          else
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
  } while (choice == 'N');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please reduce this program to the minimum size that still demonstrates the specific problem you are asking about. You are unlikely to get good answers with all of this.

Comment: I have edited my code in the original post , hope that helps! 

In addition to my issue with the mismatched do while loop, I have also noticed that return 0; is marked as unreachable code. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Julia at the end you had some } issues. I'm autoformatting the rest because it's very hard to follow as you have it written.

Comment: I think `while (choice == 'N')` choice here is used without being initialized.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Exceptions would be very useful here. Are you forbidden to use them? In any case, you would do well to make functions that do get_letter and get_number, and do something reasonable in exceptional cases. `cin >> something` can fail.

Comment: @JiveDadson are you suggesting OP throws when an extraction fails?

Comment: @Ryan - I am suggesting that get_letter and get_number could throw, and that the main loop could try/catch. This is the kind of thing that exceptions were designed for. -  An exceptional thing happened, so let's either try it again, deal with it somehow, or exit gracefully.  The alternative would be for them to return a success-flag, or better yet an std::optional or std::variant.

Comment: @RyanHaining - Teachers tend to teach beginners to do things the difficult, tedious way, because teaching them to do it the easy and elegant way is difficult for the teacher.  Teacher struggled with C before C++ made things easy, so they recapitulate the way they learned.

Comment: @JiveDadson you could just check the success of the extraction, throwing is difficult. C++ exceptions are far less common than other languages and the user entering something that doesn't match wouldn't meet most people's (that I know anyway) bar for an exceptional condition.

Comment: @JiveDadson also, having taught both of these languages I assure you that teaching exceptions is not an easy elegant, solution to the difficult, tedious means of checking success. Exceptions are a hard concept for most early students. What I've found to be most effective is to start by not checking for any error conditions, then showing them how to make their code more robust. It sucks to know they are missing pieces but it's hard to make progress otherwise.

Comment: @RyanHaining - We disagree. For me exceptions are much easier than imposing the requirement of checking return codes.  Nothing hard about `throw "Letter entered is not one of c,t,7,V";` or whatever.  I cannot speak for most people, but for me bad input is the very essence of an exceptional condition. It's like asking an allocator for more memory than it can provide. In the present case, the user is asked for a particular letter or number, but does not provide it. That necessitates an exceptional control path.  It is not a fatality, but it is something unusual that must be dealt with.

Comment: @RyanHaining - I taught both C and C++ at the university level, and I taught C++ in industry.  I had no problem with teaching the cool parts of C++.  Here's a very good lecture you might want to watch. https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: @JiveDadson I'll have to watch this in full later but skimming it I agree with everything I see. I've done C at freshman/sophomore level. Some sophomore level C++, senior C++, and freshman Java. Even in Java though, exceptions are tough to get to. I'm not disagreeing that they can provide cleaner solutions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using choice without reading into it. Additionally, the check `while (choice == 'N')` doesn't make sense, you want to continue while the choice is no?

Here's the gist of it with the irrelevant parts cut for brevity.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  char choice{};
  std::cout << "Welcome to the letter printer.\n";
  do {
    int s{};
    std::cout << "Enter the size: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> s;

    // ... check for size ...

    char l{};
    std::cout << "Enter the letter: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> l;

    // ... check for letter ... draw letter ...

    std::cout << "would you like to continue? (Y/N): " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> choice;
  } while (choice == 'Y');
}
```

For future reference, most of the code in your question isn't directly relevant to the problem, the restrictions on what letters to enter, the size restriction, and the drawing of the letter could all be left out when making your example. Doing this tends to reveal the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code and in the meantime I want to make a few remarks for the future.

- Before posting to StackOverflow asking for debugging, debug it yourself. I understand sometimes you may have a sore head from looking at the same code for a long time but not everyone likes debugging code here.
- Have some decency and post code that is at the least functioning to some degree. It is a complete pain trying to find **curly braces**, **commas**, **etc**. that you should have found yourself.
- Next time *isolate* your problem in your code before posting it here.

---

Regarding your code, you were thinking in the right direction.

- In `while(choice == 'N')` *[As pointed out by Raindrop7 & Ryan Haining]*, your `char choice` was undeclared. Simple fix is to declare / use the variable like `cin >> choice` in the example below.
- Name your variables with sense, it s hard to keep track of a variable when it is being used everywhere e.g. [`char s, int l`].
- Encapsulate code if it is being reused a lot e.g. [`void PrintLetter(char, int)`]

---

> Side Note: Next time you encounter a bug. Put some kind of animal toy beside you and speak your problem out to it. Usually you'll answer your own question.

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PrintLetter(char letter, int size)
{
    switch (letter)
    {
    case 'c':
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            cout << "*";
            for (int col = 0; col < size - 1; col++)
            {
                if (row == size - 1)
                {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        break;
    case 'l':
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    char letter;
    char choice;

    cout << "Welcome to the letter printer." << endl;

    do {

        cout << "Enter the size: " << endl;
        cin >> size;

        while (size < 7 || size % 2 == 0 || size < 0) {
            cout << "Invalid size. Enter the size again: " << endl;
            cin >> size;
        }

        cout << "Enter the letter: " << endl;
        cin >> letter;

        while (letter != 'c') {
            cout << "Invalid letter. Enter the letter again: " << endl;
            cin >> letter;
        }

        PrintLetter(letter, size); // Print Letter In Here, Function At The Top

        cout << "Would you like to continue? [Y,N]" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

    }while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'); // End Do While

    return 0;
} // End Main
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I apologize for my disorganized code. I have only been learning C++ for a couple of weeks and feel a little lost. I appreciated your understanding and advice :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to accept only the letters j, e, or c. Right now I have the while loop invalidating all letters other than c, but I need it to also accept j and e.

Comment: That’s pretty impressive for a few weeks though. Keep at it!

Comment: The code I’ve posted includes extra letters. Look at the function at the top of the CPP file. Read it and youll understand that you can add in new cases. Just don’t forget to add a *break;* at the end of each case.

Comment: Read the comments under your post, quite a few good ideas are writing there for that.